# Problem with $y'=x^2+y^2$ when $y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, nonlinear-analysis

Referring to my question "[Simple non-linear differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1704947/simple-nonlinear-differential-equation)" and the associated answers and comments, the provided solutions in terms of fractional order Bessel functions or $\frac12$ order parabolic cylinder functions all seem to have a problem with requiring $y(0) = 0$. Never the less the series $$y = \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^7}{63} + \frac{2x^{11}}{2079} + ..... $$ is a solution with $y(0) = 0$ so can anybody please explain why the Wolfram-solutions fail at $x =0$?

Comment: What is that series? Where did you get it or how did you derive it?

Comment: Putting y=z*x^3 and t = x^4 gives the related equation 4*t*z' = 1-3*z+t*z^2 from which it is easy to calculate successive derivatives z", z"', .... of z at t = 0 and thus find the Taylor series for z(t) and thus for y(x) = x^3*z(x^4)

Comment: Interesting... So it appears that the solution set changes upon transformation. Where did you get this problem from? Also, does the Taylor Series match up with the original Differential Equation when plotted and when testes numerically?

Comment: Near x = 0 we have y = x^3/3 + O(x^7) and y'=x^2 +O1(x^6) while y^2 = O2(x^6) so y'-x^2=O2(x^6) -O1(x^6) = O(x^6) so things match near x = 0. Also the series match the original equation the next terms being 17/3/72765, 46/3/4147605 and 15178/3/22036225365 for x^23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in the solution given by Wolfram you let $C[1]\to\infty$, you obtain the solution wth $y(0)=0$:
$$
y(x)=-\dfrac{x^2\,J_{-\frac{5}{4}}\Bigl(\dfrac{x^2}{2}\Bigr)-x^2\,
   J_{\frac{3}{4}}\Bigl(\dfrac{x^2}{2}\Bigr)+J_{-\frac{1}{4}}\Bigl(\dfrac{x^2}{2}\Bigr)}{2\,x\,J_{-\frac{1}{4}}\Bigl(\dfrac{x^2}{2}\Bigr)}.
$$

Comment: This only leaves y ~ -1/(2*x) which goes to infinity as x approaches 0 so I don't see the relevance.

Comment: Using `Series` Mathematica gives $$\text{Series}[y[x], \{x, 0, 10\}] // \text{FullSimplify}=\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^7}{63}+O\left(x^{11}\right)
$$

Comment: If on the other hand you put c1=0 then y=-x*Bessel(-3/4,x^2/2)/BesselJ(1/4,x^2/2). However the Wolfram-input: 0 to 1 plot -x*Bessel(-3/4,x^2/2)/BesselJ(1/4,x^2/2) shows a curve going to infinity for x going to zero, which must be wrong!

Comment: As a matter of reference BesselJ(a,z)~(z/2)^a/Gamma(a+1) for small z so the plot near x = 0 of the Wolfram solution for c1=0 approaches y ~-5/x which is a bit steeper than the plotted curve.

Comment: I owe Julián an apology because I misinterpreted the way he wrote the solution. Using the small x approximation (G ~gammafunct) J(a,x^2/2)~(x/2)^(2a)/G(1+a) the solution near 0 becomes (c1G(1/4)x^3/3+G(-1/4))/(2c1G(1/4)-xG(-1/4)) ,which is x^3/6 as c1 goes to infinity, so in this case y(0)=0 as Julián stated. However the correct approximation is y~x^3/3 not x^3/6. I have redone the calculations several times and always get the factor 2 disrepancy. Maybe somebody can check if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram now shows the answer together with sample graphs (which it not did before).
[image: I have taken a screenshot of the result as referenced below].

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to use the Bessel functions recurrence relations with respect to order and obtained this simplyfied expression
[image: final solution]
which does approach x^3/3 for small x. 
Further, I have veryfied by hand that it is actually the solution.
PROBLEM SOLVED!